# How does the Amazon Prime Gaming rewards system work?

Tags: twitch, amazon-prime-gaming

I was wondering, whenever I log into Twitch, I see the notifications of past Amazon Prime Gaming rewards and most of them have a claim button.

Since I have never bought the subscription, I wanted to know if I bought the subscription will I be able to claim these past rewards (or expired rewards?) or the claim button is a bug or an error that never got fixed?

Answer (score 3):

Every reward has a window you can claim it in. When the window passes you cannot get the reward anymore. If it has a claim button that window has not passed, and you can claim it while you have an active subscription. Once you claimed the items, you do not need the subscription to keep the items.

You can see the status of all your claimable rewards at: https://gaming.amazon.com

Old rewards whose windows have passed are removed from the list and are not visible.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the question, I will mark it once i get the subscription. also another matter, my related amazon account has been banned and closed and requires contacting support for further access, but my twitch account still works without any problems so far, is it safe to buy the subscription without intending to verify my amazon account via support? will the subscription be available via twitch only?

Comment: @Hitman2847 You'll almost certainly need an active Amazon account. You purchase a Prime subscription - which Prime Gaming is one of the benefits of - for your Amazon account, and then you can (optionally) link your Twitch and Amazon accounts to get the very few additional Twitch-specific benefits. All of the other benefits of Prime Gaming are available without having a Twitch account.

Comment: ah, got it , so no way of getting it without verifying my account